# Jasmine complains about $apply

Tags: javascript, angularjs-scope, jasmine

I am writing jasmine tests for our javascript/angular code.  I found that much of our code uses `$scope.$apply()` either by itself for wrapping functions in the `$apply()`.  The test is complaining about `$apply`

> TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method `'$apply'`.

When I take this out this error goes away, but our code doesn't work properly.  Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Can you post the tests and the code they're testing?

Comment: Your DI probably isn't working. Post test code

Answer (score 0):

can you please add some code?

Are you testing a controller?
how do you inject the $scope?

if you are doing somthing like:

```
ctrl = $controller('MyCtrl', {
    $scope:{}
});
```

this is your problem, because you should create a new scope using the $rootScope:

```
ctrl = $controller('MyCtrl', {
    $scope: $rootScope.$new()
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ronapelbaum/pkhaxmdg/

Comment: Yes that was it - I was creating the scope incorrectly.  thank you!